# Hornetq: move message from a queue to another queue using jmx management

Tags: java, jmx, hornetq

I'd like to move message from DLQ queue to another queue using JMX management tool.

Normally we will use moveMessages method of JMSQueueControl interface:

- moveMessages(String filter, String otherQueueName) 
        Moves all the message corresponding to the specified filter to the specified other queue.

My question is, how can I use this method with the following call:

/org.hornetq:module=JMS,type=Queue,name="DLQ"/moveMessages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use following CLI command to move messages from DLQ queue to another queue.

> /subsystem=messaging/hornetq-server=default/jms-queue=DLQ:move-messages(filter="",other-queue-name=QUEUE_TO_SEND)

If you want to go with JMX console, correct mbean is

> jboss.as:subsystem=messaging,hornetq-server=default,jms-queue=DLQ

and code will look like

> ObjectName memoryMXBean=new ObjectName("jboss.as:subsystem=messaging,hornetq-server=default,jms-queue=DLQ");
>
> connection.invoke(moveMessages, null, "QUEUE_TO_SEND");

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your use case, you can also use a tool like [JMSToolBox](https://sourceforge.net/projects/jmstoolbox/) to drag and drop your messages from one queue to another